# format currency regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to display a formatted number on a web page using JavaScript. I want to format it so that there are commas in the right places. How would I do this with a regular expression? I've gotten as far as something like this:

I am trying to use regular expression using JavaScript to format currency for both in English and in French. Based on my language it should use a particular regular expression. 
The English is working well but am trying to figure out the French.

```
return "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
```

This is working for English.
So my 5000 get converted to $5,000.00 this is fine.

I need French to looks like this 5 000,00 $

Comment: I'm not sure if regex is the right tool for that. But I guess this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/4028085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return num = num.substring(1).replace(/,/g , " ").replace(".", ",") + " $";
```

Use this to English formatted num.

Comment: the substring is not working
i used num.toFixed(2).replace(/,/g, " ").replace(".", ",") + " $"; 
its working to an extend: for example:
using the regular expression 125900 is coming as 125900,00 $
but i want something like 125 900,00 $